# Issue in Updating an Array Object in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update an Array object based on a condition. Following is my scenario :-

[image]

I want to update status from current to archive.

I have tried many things for hours but still no luck. Like this :-

```
db.user.update({
    'injury._id': ObjectId("5374cb4d1e0386c02800006a"),
    'injury.injurydata.locationaddressinjury': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'status': 'current'
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'injury.injurydata.locationaddressinjury.status': 'archive'
    }
})
```

Comment: Please note the format of your code. And also a code sample other than the picture would be more easier for us to read.

Comment: The exact same screenshot was used to ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23693889/2313887) just days ago. Your code example is different but the question is still basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

The picture made it hard to read the structure of your data. But I guess the update you are looking for would be something like this:

```
db.user.update({
    'injury._id': ObjectId("5374cb4d1e0386c02800006a"),
    'injury.injurydata.locationaddressinjury': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'status': 'current'
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'injury.injurydata.locationaddressinjury.$.status': 'archive'
    }
});
```

The $ would refer to the element you found. While if you are looking for a way to update all element at one time. I'm afraid $elemMatch would just match the first element that satisfies  your condition.

Comment: Nested array, matches the first array found. So if the match was the second element in the inner array but the top level array was the first element, then the matched index would still be 0 and not 1 as required. Any occurrences where this worked would just be dumb luck.